# How to make "Get Help" entries for custom package?

Tags: packages, documentation

I've got a small collection of Mathematica tools that I'd like to make into a package. One of the nicest features in Mathematica is the ability to right click on any built-in function and just select "Get Help" to see detailed documentation on usage, examples, etc.

How do I achieve this functionality in my custom package, so users can "Get Help" on my functions in the same way?